# dojox.form.Rating Not Appearing in Post Data

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a included a Dojo star rating widget (dojox.form.Rating) in a Dojo form but when submitted, it doesn't appear.

```
<div dojoType="dojox.form.Rating" numStars="5" id="field_3177" value="3"></div>
```

The documentation doesn't mention adding a name attribute, but even if I add one, it doesn't help.

```
<div dojoType="dojox.form.Rating" name="field_3177" numStars="5"  id="field_3177" value="3"></div>
```

Examining the rendered HTML in Firebug, it seems the hidden input field has no name attribute - which would explain why it doesn't appear in the POSTed data.

```
<input type="hidden" dojoattachpoint="focusNode" value="3" id="field_3177" tabindex="0">
```

Is there something I should do before submitting?

Comment: I solved this by monkey patching the hidden input to have name attribute. But surely that can't be the right way to do it. Can it?

Comment: This is the monkey patch that fixed it: function( id )
  {
      
   dojo.attr( id, 'name', id );
  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a name to the widget, i.e.

```
<div dojoType="dojox.form.Rating" numStars="5" id="field_3177" name="field_3177" value="3"></div>
```

This is nothing special to Dojo. All input elements must have a name in order to be submitted back to the server, see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_name.asp.

UPDATE:
Sorry, didn't see that you'd already tried adding a name param. I'd argue this is a bug in either the Form or (more likely) the rating widget. If you submit your form via XHR using dijit.form.Form.getValues() then you'll get the rating widget included - if you have a name. But if you use the native form submit then you don't.

I've created a test case at hhttp://telliott.net/dojoExamples/dojo-ratingInFormExample.html. You can get this to work for non-XHR form submission by quickly iterating through the values returned by getValues() and building the query string yourself. Not ideal. I suspect the template for the rating should be updated to put the name attribute onto the input node rather than the top level node.

Comment: See the 2nd snippet of code I posted: "The documentation doesn't mention adding a name attribute, but even if I add one, it doesn't help."

Answer (score 0):

Silly question:

have you added dojo.require("dojox.form.Rating"); to your code?

Hope it helps you.

//Daniel